# Creating a small dialog box inside a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

What i am trying to do is, instead of creating a pop-up page i want to make a dialog box with information that appears when clicked on an image. [image: Prefer the same kind of box]

Comment: What do you mean by dialog box? the screenshot you've posted looks like dialog information to me

Comment: yes, dialog information. When i click on the image i need to get this.

Comment: What code have you tried? are you using jQuery? Bootstrap? Please provide more information

Comment: This is not mine. just from a random site. i need direction on how to proceed.

Comment: Try this http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sooner you can use Bootstrap modals,your can call that popup using  two ways

this is modal popup content

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
 ... pop up content
</div>
```

1)`$('#myModal').modal();` (jquery call)

2)`<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>`

[demo and documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1):

Well essentially this is just a modal window. You can find libraries for getting a modal window you could use Bootstrap 3.

Well here's a CSS only solution for the above similar effect:
This is completely responsive and uses transforms so will work IE9 and above.
here's the bin:
http://jsbin.com/caqacokuqa